# It was one of a few houses (that were) (fully) built?

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses, semantics

> It was one of a few houses (that were) (fully) built.

I want to say that the house was done, does just ***built*** mean that or should it be ***fully built*** ?

and is ***that were*** necessary or optional?

Comment: You might want to provide a little bit more context regarding your objectives with this sentence. For instance, is there any need to say **fully** built? (That might be the case if later you refer to other houses that are **partly** built for example).

Comment: Our neighborhood was quite new. Only a few years ago, my house was one of a few houses (that were) (fully) built and inhabited. The neighborhood quickly became a community. On my block,...move on to something else. @JMB

Comment: "completed/finished/delivered" could be other options...

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Note that the [tag:grammar] tag is a generic tag for people who do not know what tags to use, so I removed it. It shouldn't be added back. See the [tag description](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/grammar/info).

Comment: Sorry, it's just that I thought the semantic tag was not enough as I had a question about the grammar as well. But I see that you replaced it with a more specific one, thanks! @EddieKal

Answer (score 1):

The identifying relative clause of the example sentence is highlighted below:

> It was one of a few houses **that were fully built**.

According to the *Oxford Guide to English Grammar*, Eastwood (1994) p. 361:

> Sometimes we can use a participle without a relative pronoun or an
> auxiliary.
>
> *That man **sitting next to Angela** never said a word.*

In your example sentence, you can use a passive participle (built) in a reduced relative clause.  Note that this usage is common in informal language.

These are fine:

> It was one of the few houses fully built.
>
> It was one of the few houses built.    (modifier can be removed)

Comment: It might be notable that the implications of each usage are slightly different.